# Toggle input field of an admin form required and not required by javascript Magento2

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, adminform, catalog-price-rules, schedule

I am trying to make a field mandatory/not mandatory through javascript in Magento2, but it's not working. Can someone please suggest?

```
define([
'underscore',
'uiRegistry',
'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/select',
'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal'
], function (_, uiRegistry, select, modal) {
'use strict';

return select.extend({

    /**
     * On value change handler.
     *
     * @param {String} value
     */
    onUpdate: function (value) {

        var field1 = document.getElementsByName("staging[end_time]")[0];
        if (value === 1) {
            field1.classList.add("required");//not working
        } else {
            field1.classList.remove("required"); //not working
        }

        return this._super();
    },
});
});
```

Comment: is it your custom field on frontend or backend?

Comment: Its in backend, related to this
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/229932/add-custom-form-element-on-catalogrulestaging-update-form-and-make-other-field-m